# What regex can I use to match only letters, numbers, and one space between each word?

Tags: regex

How can I create a regex expression that will match only letters and numbers, and **one** space between each word?

**Good Examples:**

```
Amazing

Hello World

I am 500 years old
```

**Bad Examples:**

```
Hello  world

I am 500 years      old.

I    am   Chuck Norris
```

Comment: Do you want to match a line containing multiple words like these or only one word at a time? Can you please elaborate with some examples what is it exactly that you want to match?

Comment: Why the requirement to disallow multiple spaces? Is it really that important, or can you just automatically convert all multiple spaces to single spaces before applying the regex? Or, is this just an academic exercise?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most regex implementations support named character classes:

```
^[[:alnum:]]+( [[:alnum:]]+)*$
```

You could be clever though a little less clear and simplify this to:

```
^([[:alnum:]]+ ?)*$
```

FYI, the second one allows a spurious space character at the end of the string. If you don't want that stick with the first regex.

Also as other posters said, if `[[:alnum:]]` doesn't work for you then you can use `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead.

Comment: I'll give you a vote if you add " ?" at the start to handle a single space at the start of the line/string (and the ^$ anchor points). Everything else seems good.

Comment: Sorry, just saw your edit. It's working great the following regex: ^([A-Za-z0-9]+ ?)*$

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+ ?)+?
```

Comment: And a space at the start of the line is handled how? :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?)*$
```

its works

Comment: This matches even if there is a trailing space at the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[a-zA-Z]+([\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ])+[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

If I understand you correctly the above regex should work.
See screenshot below:

[screenshot http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/6871/screenshotkiki056.png](http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/6871/screenshotkiki056.png)

Comment: What tool are you using testing the regex (seen on the screenshot) ?

Answer (score -1):

This would match a word

```
'[a-zA-Z0-9]+\ ?'
```

Comment: Great, now make that handle a line :-)

Comment: No, it would match *some* words. Only those containing the (ascii) ranges a-z and A-Z. The word `café` would not be matched. It would also match strings that consist solely of digits like `01012009`, something I wouldn't call a word.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question