# JS regex to match character string with maximum 1 space between tokens

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am pattern matching some strings to see if they match -

I want to accept

```
a b cde f ghijk lm n
```

but reject

```
a b    cd   ef g
```

since the latter has more than one whitespace character between tokens

I have this regex

```
new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9\s?]+$', 'ig')
```

but it doesn't currently reject strings with more than 1 whitespace character between.

Is there any easy way to augment my current regex?

thanks

Comment: The answer can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630610/regex-match-only-letters-numbers-and-one-space-between-each-word

Comment: @CameronMeador: Yes, it can be found, but not understood. The correct regex is not explained at all. Also, if there must be a support for leading/trailing whitespace, that post does not provide a working solution.

Answer (score 5):

Try this approach:

```js
var str = "a b cde f ghijk lm n";
if(str.match(/\s\s+/)){
   alert('it is not acceptable');
} else {
   alert('it is acceptable');
}
```

---

**Note:** As @Wiktor Stribizew mentioned in the comment, maybe OP wants to reject string containing some symbols like this `$`. So it would be better to use this regex in the condition:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]|\s\s+/
```

Comment: This allows strings like `$$$ $$$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well what's wrong with it? `$$$ $$$` is containing just one space and it is acceptable ... Am I right?

Comment: The pattern is `^[a-zA-Z0-9\s?]+$`. Where does it accept `$`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added a *note* to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Must you use regex?  Why not just check to see if the string has two spaces?

**JavaScript**

```
strAccept = "a b c def ghijk lm n";
strReject = "a b    cd   ef g";


function isOkay(str) {
    return str.indexOf('  ') == -1 && str.indexOf(' ') >= 0;
}


console.log(isOkay(strAccept))
console.log(isOkay(strReject))
```

**Output**

> true
>   false

JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/ta216m3v/1/

Hope that helps!

Comment: This allows strings like `$$$ $$$`, too. That is why regex is necessary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the OP stated the requirement is to accept strings with single spaces, so $$$ $$$  *should* be accepted.

Comment: No, the requirement is that the strings meet the `^[a-zA-Z0-9\s?]+$` pattern first, and *then* they should only  contain 1 space between the tokens. It can easily be solved by fixing the regexp, with no lines of redundant code.

Comment: I don't believe that is correct, but I'll leave it to the OP to clarify.

Comment: I need to verify that there are only letters and numbers *and* only single spaces, so regex is most appropriate

Answer (score 2):

Try following regex:

```
/^(\S+\s?)+$/im.test(text)
```

where `parameter text` is whatever string you want to test.

> **OUTPUT:**
>
> - `a b cde f ghijk lm n    <-- match`
> - `but reject              <-- match`
> - `a b    cd   ef g        <-- no match`

See demo https://regex101.com/r/lS4cU7/2

Answer (score 1):

If your tokens are just ASCII letters or digits, use

```
var regex = /^[a-z0-9]+(?:\s[a-z0-9]+)*$/i;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU6zK0/1)

The pattern matches:

- `^` - the start of string
- `[a-z0-9]+` - one or more letters or digits
- `(?:\s[a-z0-9]+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `\s` - any whitespace, 1 symbol
  - `[a-z0-9]+` - 0+ letters or digits
- `$` - end of string

This way, you restrict the number of spaces between "words" to just 1 occurrence.

If you plan to allow leading/trailing whitespace, add `\s*` after `^` and before `$`.

Comment: will this allow a trailing whitespace, as is?

Comment: If you want to allow leading/trailing whitespace, just add `\s*`: `var regex = /^\s*[a-z0-9]+(?:\s[a-z0-9]+)*\s*$/i;`